# Should I use a singleton.?

Tags: c++, opengl, design-patterns

I am planning on making a 3D scene editor app using c++ and open gl. And I have to keep track of the current loaded project and different  scenes it contains also the user preferences and other things. The best solution I can think of is to wrap them in a context class which will be a singleton. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Not a good idea, probably. One reason is technical. The actual OpenGL context's lifetime is limited and is far shorter than app itself, usually related to surface you're outputting to. You would need to initialize context after your visualizing window is ready and de-initialize it before window is gone. Trying to do so when window gone may end to undefined behaviour depending on platform. In some cases you might need several contexts.

Another reason is, it doesn't look like proper separation of responsibilities. User settings aren't part of context, but some may affect only a single render pass (out of plural). You likely would have Preferences, Renderer which would be an interface to Context manager, Geometries, Textures (or materials) separate, an Scene Manager as well (think of scene tree in Blender or DAZ studio, each item in scene can have separate user settings, regarding how to visualize them).